# getting columnCount = 1 in jdbc metaData

Tags: java, jdbc

I keep on getting  wrong number of columns in table  what am i doing wrong here's the code
is this not correct ?  what am i doing wrong ?   how to I get the amount of columns that a particular table has then ? :

```
public int getTableInfo(String tableName, String db, Boolean columnCount,
        Boolean rowCount) {

    TABLE = tableName;

    Connection getTableInfoConn = this.getConnect_to_DB(db);

    try {
        PreparedStatement prepStatement = getTableInfoConn
                .prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `" + tableName
                        + "`");

        ResultSet res = prepStatement.executeQuery();

        if ((columnCount == false) && (rowCount == false)
                || (columnCount == null) && (rowCount == false)
                || (columnCount == false) && (rowCount == null)
                || (columnCount == null) && (rowCount == null)) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "uno de los booleanos debe ser TRUE", null,
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);

        } else {

            if (columnCount == false && rowCount == true
                    || columnCount == null) {

                while (res.next()) {

                    resultMetaData = res.getInt(1);
                }
            } else if (columnCount == true && rowCount == false
                    || rowCount == null) {

                metaData = res.getMetaData();



                resultMetaData = metaData.getColumnCount();


            }

        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error in getTableInfo():" + e);
    }

    return resultMetaData;

}
```

and main method is =

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConectorBaseDatos dbconector = new ConectorBaseDatos();

    int numFilas = dbconector.getTableInfo("arbitros","fifa", false, true);

    System.out.println("Numero de filas de arbitros es : "+ numFilas);

    int numColumnas = dbconector.getTableInfo("arbitros", "fifa", true, false);

   System.out.println("numero de columnas es : " + numColumnas);
}
```

why is `columnCount  = 1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you're issuing here is:

```
select count(*) from arbitros;
```

The result is going to be a single column, single row, just holding the number of rows in "arbitros".  That result has a single column (named "count(*)" or something similar).

If you want the number of columns in arbitros, the query you need is:

```
select * from arbitros;
```